# Calculate Segment:Offset from absolute address

Tags: assembly, x86-16, memory-segmentation

I can calculate an address `Segment:Offset` as `Segment` * 0x10 + `Offset`. But how do I calculate the opposite?

E.g. how do I get from `0xF4170` to `F400:0170` and from `0xACF04` to `ABCD:1234`?

Comment: Another recent duplicate: [How to get segment memory address, when i have physical address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62299565)

Comment: Another recent duplicate: [How to get segment memory address, when i have physical address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62299565).  And see [Find Segment address from given physical and effective address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56072884) re: splitting `0xACF04` into parts if you know you want `0x1234` as the offset part, instead of something simple with leading zeros in the offset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be required to have either the base or the offset to start with, along with the linear address, as multiple `Segment:Offset` pairs can map to the same linear address.

so if we have the segment `0xF400` and the linear address `0xF4170`, we get the offset being `0xF4170 - (0xF400 << 4)` which is `0x170`.

---

Doing this with only knowing the linear address doesn't have a unique solution, so you have to choose a convention for splitting a 20-bit address into a 16-byte-aligned `seg` part and a byte offset.  One possible function is this:

- `Segement = linear >> 4`  (top 16 bits)
- `offset = linear & 0x0F` (low 4 bits)

You might choose a canonical form with 12:8 bits, leaving room for future expansion with wider linear addresses.

Comment: thank you for that answer. Anyhow, I don't care if there are multiple possibilities of pairs Segment:Offset. Do you know any way to calculate just one of those without knowing as well the segment as the offset and without doing any kind of "bruteforce"?

Comment: @muffel: see my updated answer. this is one of the problems where you need more than one equation or some given side affect that allows you to solve for two unknowns.

Comment: Splitting a linear address into `seg:off` is precise but not *unique*.  There are many possible solutions.  @muffel: The most obvious choices for a canonical form are with a 4-bit offset, or with a 4-bit segment value, putting the other 16 bits of a 20-bit linear address into the other component of the seg:off.  In a related question, [Find Segment address from given physical and effective address](//stackoverflow.com/q/56072884), the `off` part is known so we can simply solve for the segment.

Comment: "should" isn't a strong enough word for the linear address of a `seg:`.  It automatically is aligned by definition of how it factors into the calculation.  You can have a data or code "segment" in source code that isn't (16-byte) paragraph-aligned, but then the lowest `OFFSET` in that program segment isn't guaranteed to be 0.  Don't confuse asm source sections that call themselves segments with actual segment register values.

Comment: This needed a major edit; unless I was totally misunderstanding something, it looked wrong.  The "function" involving `& ~16` made no sense, that clears one bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes that appears to have been a typo on my part, should have been `~15`. good catch