# How to get segment memory address, when i have physical address?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, real-mode, memory-segmentation

The physical address of the memory cell is given in the form 1A32H. What is the address of the beginning of the memory segment.  Or more exactly, the seg:off address I should use to access it.

Can someone explain me step by step how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which CPU type do you use? x86 real-mode? x86 protected-mode? Any other CPU type that has "segments" (such as 65C816)?

Comment: im using x86 real-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In x86 real-mode, the physical address is calculated as:

> 16 * segment + offset

So the physical address 1A32H can be accessed in different ways:

> Segment = 1A3H, Offset = 2 or
>   Segment = 1A2H, Offset = 12H or
>   Segment = 1A1H, Offset = 22H or
>   ...
>   Segment = 0, Offset = 1A32H

It depends on your use case which combination of segment and offset you chose:

If the address is the start address of a memory range (e.g. the first element of an array), you would use a higher segment value (segment 1A3H, offset 2H).

If the address is the end address of a memory range (e.g. initial stack pointer), you would use a lower segment value (segment 0, offset 1A32H).

Please also note that the offset is a 16-bit number.

So physical addresses >= 2^16 cannot be accessed using a segment value of 0:

Address 1A325H (as an example) can be accessed using:

> Segment = 1A32H, Offset = 5 or
>   Segment = 1A31H, Offset = 15H or
>   ...
>   Segment = 0A33H, Offset = 0FFF5H